# Input folder path error for csv automation report

Tags: python, pandas

Please help me with this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\Desktop\HC\HC.CHECKER.py", line 17, in 
read_file = pd.read_excel(abs_folder_path, sheet_name = 'MSAN Cabinets')
File "C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
File "C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 1376, in **init**
ext = inspect_excel_format(
File "C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 1250, in inspect_excel_format
with get_handle(
File "C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 795, in get_handle
handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\Desktop\HC'

When running this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os


print("Fixed Network Health Check Checker")

folder_path = name = input("Enter the folder path of your Raw files: ")

abs_folder_path = os.path.abspath(folder_path)


read_file = pd.read_excel(abs_folder_path, sheet_name = 'MSAN Cabinets')

read_file.to_csv(abs_folder_path, index = None, header = True)

df = pd.read_csv(abs_folder_path, encoding='unicode_escape')

#fixed
df['MSAN Interface'] = df['MSAN Interface'].replace(np.nan, 0)

df['ACCESS Interface 1 (IPRAN, ATN, LSA, VLAN)'] = df['ACCESS Interface 1 (IPRAN, ATN, LSA, VLAN)'].replace(np.nan, 0)

df['Homing AG2'] = df['Homing AG1'].replace(np.nan, 0)

df = df.iloc[:11255]


# filter "REGION" and drop unnecessary columns

f_df1 = df[df['REGION'] == 'MIN']
dropcols_df1 = f_df1.drop(df.iloc[:, 1:6], axis = 1)
dropcols_df2 = dropcols_df1.drop(df.iloc[:, 22:27], axis = 1)
dropcols_df3 = dropcols_df2.drop(df.iloc[:, 37:50], axis = 1)


# filter "MSAN Interface" and filter the peak util for >= 50%

f_d2 = dropcols_df3['MSAN Interface'] != 0
msan_int = dropcols_df3[f_d2]
f_msan_int = msan_int['Peak Util'] >= 0.5
new_df = msan_int[f_msan_int]


# filter "ACCESS Interface 1 (IPRAN, ATN, LSA, VLAN)" and filter the peak util for >= 50%

fblank_msan_int = dropcols_df3['MSAN Interface'] == 0
msan_int1 = dropcols_df3[fblank_msan_int]
f_df3 = dropcols_df3['ACCESS Interface 1 (IPRAN, ATN, LSA, VLAN)'] != 0
access_int1 = dropcols_df3[f_df3]
f_access_int1 = access_int1['Peak Util.1'] >= 0.5
new_df1 = access_int1[f_access_int1]


# filter "Homing AG1" and filter the peak util for >= 50%

fblank_msan_int1 = dropcols_df3['MSAN Interface'] == 0
msan_int2 = dropcols_df3[fblank_msan_int1]
f_access_int2 = msan_int2['ACCESS Interface 1 (IPRAN, ATN, LSA, VLAN)'] == 0
new_df2 = msan_int2[f_access_int2]
ag1 = new_df2['Peak Util.3'] >= 0.5
new_df3 = new_df2[ag1]

# Concatenate all DataFrames

pdList = [new_df, new_df1, new_df3]
final_df = pd.concat(pdList)


print(final_df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False))
```

Could someone help me.
Python version 3.9.12 Windows 10 x64

Thanks

Comment: This is the key part of your error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Dell Latitude 7480\Desktop\HC'` . Make sure you have the right permission or try to write to a different path that you do have the right permission.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my code that caused this error to?